# ¿Liberar memoria fuera de función?

Tags: c, manejo-de-memoria

Me surgió una duda respecto al manejo de la memoria en **C**, por lo que tengo entendido yo no puedo retornar direcciones de memoria locales a una función (de hecho esto genera un **warning** en el compilador) pero si se puede si es que estas direcciones de memoria fueron reservadas mediante `malloc()` (o `calloc()`, etc), ahora por lo que sé cada vez que reservamos memoria debemos liberarla al finalizar el programa (para esto existe `free()`) o al dejar de utilizarla (ya que esto no se hace de manera automática). Tomando en cuenta todo esto... Si yo tengo una función que retorna un `string` (con memoria reservada dinámicamente claro), digamos por ejemplo:

```
char *nombre();
```

y la utilizo de esta manera:

```
printf("Hola: %s",nombre());
```

Como al salir de la función pierdo la dirección de memoria ¿esta queda almacenada sin que yo pueda hacer nada? ¿Lo mas correcto seria almacenar la dirección de memoria retornada por la función, imprimirla y luego liberarla?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: No necesariamente debes usar siempre`malloc` o `calloc`, puedes usar una funcion llamada `strdup()`, esta abre el espacio que abriria el `malloc` y retorna la cadena, obviamente lo mas conveniente seria liberar despues de usar.

Comment: Creo que esa función no forma parte del estándar de C

Comment: Tienes razon, aca vemos un ejemplo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12984948/why-is-strdup-considered-to-be-evil igual, en la gcc (Linux) no tiene problemas cuando se usa esta funcion, obviamente, esta te ahorra el hacer el `malloc(sizeof(...))` y todo eso.

Comment: El problema es que se pierde parte de la semántica y modularidad de la aplicación debido a que la función debería hacer todo el trabajo. No liberar la memoria fuera... y evidentemente debería apegarme al estándar y no utilizar esa función... a fin de cuentas ¿No se le puede delegar toda la tarea a la función?

Comment: Pues, siendo sincero, en esa parte no he conocido que C lo haga automaticamente....Pero! Has de cuenta que es como estandares y reglas que se han apegado a los principios del lenguaje, que quiero decir...Antes podias encontrar la palabra _register_ y esta accedia al procesador y guardaba como un registro, pero si lees veras que esta funcion, en la actualidad se delega al SO donde guardar la variable realmente.

Comment: Si haces la prueba de asignar un malloc, hasta un numero muy grande de bytes y despues finalizas el programa, mientras miras un monitor del sistema, veras que despues de la finalizacion del programa todo vuelve a la normalidad, en dicho caso, creo que no hay problema con dejar un recurso sin liberar. En mi suposicion

Comment: Es evidente que los SO modernos deben tener un sistema de gestión de memoria automática para asegurar el buen uso de los recursos de la computadora, pero C no es un lenguaje que corra solo en este tipo de computadoras, puede por ejemplo, ser utilizado en un Arduino y este claramente no realizara ninguna de esas tareas automáticamente y por ende lo que mencionas no es portable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Efectivamente; lo correcto es **liberar** toda la memória que no uses.

```
char *tmp = mifunc( );

printf( "%s", tmp );

free( tmp );
```

Todas las funciones de la biblioteca estandard indican (si es aplicable) que sucede con la memória que utilizan.

Algunas te *ceden* el control de esa memória, siendo **tu** responsabilidad el liberarla; caso de, por ejemplo, `strdup( )`.

Otras utilizan un *buffer* interno, que reutilizan cada vez que las llames. **No** tienes que liberarlo tú (so pena de provocar errores), pero tienes que controlar el uso de dichas funciones, para no interferir una llamada con otra.

Todo bloque de memória que asignes mediante `malloc( )` y no liberes **no será liberado** nunca por el sistema; es un error común, llamado *perdida de memória*.

Si te interesa el tema, puedes buscar información sobre *allocators*: las funciones que realizan la reserva, reasignación y liberación de los bloques de memória. Hay muchos: jemalloc, tlsf, ... mas o menos adecuados para ciertos usos: velocidad, compactación, *multithread*, ...

También existen mecanismos para *autoliberar* la memória cuando no se utiliza: los *recolectores de memória*; por ejemplo, el Boehm-Demers-Weiser, utilizables desde C como librerías.

Por último, existen técnicas para *simplificar* la liberación (en teoría), como el conteo de referencias, las listas enlazadas de referencias, ...

La gestión de memória es *todo un mundo*.

**EDITO**

Si lo que quieres es que la función se encargue de todo, se me ocurren varias opciones:

**1** - Usar un buffer estático:

```
#define TAM 1024

char *funct( ... ) {
  static char buff[TAM];
  ...
  return buff;
}
```

Ventajas:

- Simple de usar.
- No requiere ningún manejo de memória.

Inconvenientes:

- Tamaño limitado.
- Problemas con uso multi-hilo.

**2** - Usar un buffer interno.

```
char *funct( ... ) {
  static char *buff = NULL;
  ...
  if( !buff ) {
    buff = (char *)malloc( ... )
  }
  ...
  return buff;
}
```

Similar a **1**, puedes cambiar el tamaño de forma dinámica, ajustandolo a lo necesario en cada llamada.

Ventajas:

- Simple de usar.
- Mínima gestión de memória.

Inconvenientes:

- Problemas con uso multi-hilo.
- **Siempre** estarás usando ese bloque de memória (nunca se libera del todo).
- **Gestionas** la memória, por lo que debes de estar preparado para fallos en las llamadas a `malloc( )` o `realloc( )` que uses.

Si el uso es más *complejo*, deberás utilizar otras soluciones: funciones de inicialización y finalización, orientación a objetos, ...

Comment: Claro lo supuse, pero no quería hacer eso debido a que por un tema de modularidad la función debería hacer todo el trabajo.

Comment: Puedes utilizar un *buffer* interno estático `static char buff[MAX_SIZE]` que no tendrías que liberar, pero cuidado con usar múltiples hilos, o con pasarte del tamaño máximo, u, obviamente, con liberarlo por descuido, que te producirá un error.